# Loading data in background for view controller from which i've popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an application in which i load video from internet in webView in a player and before video gets loaded in pop to view controller and seeing activity indicator animating in status bar and after few seconds i am able to hear audio of the video i've selected though i'm not on the webView view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should `nil` the `webView` and your `player` in `dealloc` of your `viewController`.Some times session is retained you can terminate by `niling` webView

Comment: I've tried self.webView = nil in view will disappear but still able to hear audio of video.